# sprintf throws warning with % in string

Tags: php, printf

I am using sprintf on some html that contains a table:

```
<table width="100%"....
```

It seems that % symbol is causing warnings.  How do I properly escape that character?

Doing

```
<table width="100%%"....
```

Strips the trailing " as well as the % symbol giving me

```
<table width="100 border="0"...
```

Comment: OK, it was PEBKAC.  I was sprintf'in it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape it with another `%`:

```
<table width="100%%"....
```

Comment: If I do that I end up with:

    <table width="100 border="0"

It strips out both % symbols and the closing quotation mark.